# How to set Routes Group in Go Fiber V2 from separated file?

Tags: go, go-fiber

I  want to make seperate files for each sub main routes. I am using go 1.17

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "rolling_glory_go/routes"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        err := c.SendString("Hello golang!")
        return err
    })

    routes.R_login(app.Group("/login"))
    routes.R_users(app.Group("/users"))

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

I want to import routes from `r_login.go` and `r_users.go` so i could manage many routes from different files and not put many routes from single file in `main.go`. I got an error like this.

```
.\main.go:17:26: cannot use app.Group("/login") (type fiber.Router) as type *fiber.Group in argument to routes.R_login: need type assertion
.\main.go:18:26: cannot use app.Group("/users") (type fiber.Router) as type *fiber.Group in argument to routes.R_users: need type assertion
```

My Structure Folder

[image]

r_login.go

```
package routes

import "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"

func R_login(router *fiber.Group) {
    router.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("respond with a resource")
    })
}
```

r_users.go

```
package routes

import "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"

func R_users(router *fiber.Group) {
    router.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("respond with a resource")
    })
}
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have `app.Group("/login")` which of type `fiber.Router`
, just modify `R_login` to have it accept this type.

```
package routes

import "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"

func R_login(router fiber.Router) {
    router.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("respond with a resource")
    })
}
```

Comment: i got this error `routes\r_login.go:6:8: router.Get undefined (type *fiber.Router is pointer to interface, not interface)`

Comment: Just edit my answer, remove the * will do.

Comment: but why i have to type fiber.Router while this repo https://github.com/vo9312/gofiber-starter/tree/48545ddee3b5d84d6d228e3d3dc27a3a468cec48, and see this its route said `*fiber.Group`
https://github.com/vo9312/gofiber-starter/blob/48545ddee3b5d84d6d228e3d3dc27a3a468cec48/routes/users.go

Comment: Though the repo use fiber without v2, I believe it would not works,  cause it pass an interface to an func which requires a pointer to a struct.

Comment: thank sir, now i know and also it works

Comment: i cant find that information in fiber doc, how do u know that

Comment: read the code, and figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone is still having issues I'm doing this in fiber/v2

```
func BookRouter(router fiber.Router) {
    router.Get("/", GetBook)
    router.Get("/all", GetBooks)
    router.Post("/", NewBook)
    router.Delete("/", DeleteBook)
}
 
    books := app.Group("/book")  //server.go
    books.Route("/", book.BookRouter)
```